# Insert and click on links on the web page with selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to simulate clicking on a link on a whatsapp web page.
This link is not on the page but I have it stored on my database. I had thought of inserting a web element on the page and then clicking but I think I did not succeed.
Here is my code:

```
  DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
  Dim bot As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  bot.SetProfile "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
  bot.Start "chrome", "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
  bot.Open "/"
  bot.Wait 40000
  Dim link As SeleniumWrapper.WebElement
  link = ("https://wa.me/number?text=Ciao%20namenumber")
  bot.FindElementByName("link").Click
```

I need to do this because by clicking in this way the page immediately sends me back to the chat to open.
can you help me? could there be some better way?

Comment: Start with why. Why do you want to simulate a link from web.whatsapp.com? If you want a referer header, you can just set it.

Comment: using that link I noticed that you open the chat quickly on that message. If you have other methods please help me ...

Comment: erik can you help me?

Comment: Nope, I'm still very much unclear on what you're trying to achieve, and what exactly isn't working. You haven't shared any error message or something like it. I'd start by answering QHarr's questions, he's very experienced with Selenium and VBA.

Comment: I'm trying to get the emulation of the web whatsapp function that when it has a click to chat like https: //wa.me ..... directly opens the chat with that number

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to make sense to me. Use the link direct rather than trying to  insert into page. You are adding extra complexity for what is in effect just a navigation to a new URL step.

```
'code to retrieve link from database (SQL query?)
bot.get link
```

Comment: If I use bot.get I open a page on which to click "send" ... if I click on the link directly opens the chat, and this makes everything very fast.

Comment: Hum... have you verified the link is correct in dev tools and are there any events associated with click that alter the url? Seems weird to me.

Comment: yes the link is correct. What I put is an example and there is the number. If you have whatsapp web open a link like https://wa.me/number from inside a chat and see what it does ....

Comment: Not an option on this machine. The only instances I can think of where .get doesn't work direct on a link is where the URL is relative or altered by an event. It doesn't appear to be relative. Can you share the relevant HTML using snippet tool?

Comment: sorry, maybe I did not explain well. If I use .get the link works, but it opens a new instance of web whatsapp, and this slows down the system. If the same link is opened as if it were an element of the page, the web page directly opens the chat on that number.

Comment: A new window with whataspp? A new tab with another whatsapp? If this link doesn't exist on the page where are you getting it from? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: I'm trying to get the emulation of the web whatsapp function that when it has a click to chat like https: //wa.me ..... directly opens the chat with that number

Comment: Can you use ExecuteScript passing number as argument?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not very experienced. The problem is that as suggested by ewwink when I step executescript opens the page with the link. In this case it should open the chat directly. Try on your waweb if you can. should do executescript with sending directly

Comment: I'm sorry, could I explain?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert link to the page you can use `ExecuteScript()` to insert it using javascript.

```
bot.ExecuteScript("document.body.innerHTML = '<a name=\'wa_link\' href=\'https://wa.me/number?text=Ciao%20namenumber\' style=\'position:absolute;top:0;z-index:9999;\'>wa_link</a>'")
bot.FindElementByName("wa_link").Click
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVm2F.jpg     I think you're on the right track, but it does not work ... I get this error

Comment: edited: I added `style` to the link and try add wait 2 second before clicking the link

Comment: now I see WA_LINK but the click does not work. I tried manually even at the end of the routine but it does not open the page

Comment: and if instead of inserting the link, I would just run the page opening script? The syntax? sorry i do not know javascript

Comment: try removing `+` from `...innerHTML +=` and I edited the answer to open URL using JS

Comment: now it adds the link but it makes the page gray and the click does not work. The opening page, on the other hand, works, but opens the page as if it were .get. How to simulate only what the page does by clicking on the link?

Comment: can you right click the link and `Inspect` and see if it valid link element.

Comment: <a name="wa_link" href="https://wa.me/393391918319?text=Ciao%20namenumber" style="position:absolute;top:0;z-index:9999;">wa_link</a>      here it is

Comment: I noticed that the page freezes and does not work click anywhere

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Ewwink sorry you have seen?